# Can an explanatory variable be both endogenous and exogenous?

Tags: stata, predictor, instrumental-variables, endogeneity

I have two dependent variables that I will use in two separate models (namely *math_score* & *language_score*) and one independent variable (*relative_power*) that I will use in both models using Stata 14. The two models have the same sample size. I suspect there's endogeneity in *relative_power* so I add two instruments to address this problem using **ivregress 2sls** command. When I tried to test the endogeneity with the **estat endog** command, I get different results for *relative_power*.

For the model with *math_score*, the Durbin & Wu-Hausman test statistic is significant, indicating the independent variable *relative_power* is indeed endogenous, but for *language_score* the test statistic is not significant, meaning *relative_power* is exogenous.

Does this often happen? What should I do to conclude the possible endogeneity in relative_power?

I have consulted with my Professor about this but they said it's best to look at previous studies and since previous studies claim that the independent variable that I used was endogenous they said I should treat it as such and keep using IV regression for the model with *language_score*.

Is it wise to use 2SLS regression even though the independent variable is not endogenous based on the **estat endog** test? I am a novice and have not encountered something like this before. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounded like a causal discovery task to figure out the directionality so to speak.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what relative_power means here and if the scores come from the same sample or two different ones? There could be several reasons why math and language scores could behave differently, but helpful to get additional context.

Comment: relative_power is the independent variable (it measures mother's bargaining power relative to her husband) and I use MCA to get this measure. Math & language scores are the children's test scores and I obtained both scores from the same sample and standardized them.

Answer (score 1):

In real life, a variable is either endogenous or exogenous. It can't be both, since the definition of either of those terms is the exact opposite of the other one.

If you are trying to assess whether a variable is endogenous or not using a statistical test, you may be *uncertain* whether it is endogenous or exogenous. Similarly, doing two different tests might give you two different results as here (if that never happened, they wouldn't be different tests!)

If you are uncertain, it is normally best to treat the variable as endogenous. If you do an exogenous analysis on a variable that could be endogenous it is usually useless, and readers will not trust it. conversely if you do an endogenous analysis on a variable which was exogenous, it is usually still valid (though it may not be as well powered).

Comment: Thank you for clearing up my uncertainty, I'll treat both model as endogenous then

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that a variable is both exogenous and endogenous depending on the independent variable and treatment effect you are estimating.

In your situation, it is possible that *relative_power* is exogenous to *language_score* while being endogenous towards *math_score*. When we say endogenous and exogenous, we mean one variable with respect to another. For example, in the classic example of education affecting wages, education is endogenous with respect to wages, but may not be with other variables such as ice cream price.

Ultimately, it will still depend on the context that whether you have a good reason for the exogeneity of the independent variable.